How to extract key, value items from a .json array field in Redshift?
I have a Redshift table called expenses that contains a field called priceitems. The field is of character varying data type and takes values like in a list of .json array like below:
[{"id":27,"amount":6.50,"explainer":null,"quantity":1.00000000,"quantityunit":0,"total":6.50,"billable":false,"name":"Catering","taxable":false,"servicecost_servicecostid":38038}]

I am trying to select the amount key value pair.
I try this:
SELECT 
  json_extract_path(
    json_extract_array_element_text(priceitems::json, 0),
    'amount'
  ) 
FROM 
    expenses

but I get ERROR:

type "json" does not exist [ErrorId:
1-660bdd25-14ff56ae10342e777927c54d]

I also tried:
 SELECT 
  json_extract_path_text(priceitems, 'amount')
FROM 
    expenses
where operatorid = 179 and flightid = 632432

and I get ERROR: JSON parsing error Detail: ----------------------------------------------- error: JSON parsing error code: 8001 context: invalid json object [{"id":25,"amount":495.64,"explainer":null,"quantity":1.00000000,"quantityunit":0,"total":495.64,"billable":false,"name":"Renaissance","taxable":false,"servicecost_servicecostid":38030}] query: 70157519 location: funcs_json.hpp:134 process: query0_126_70157519 [pid=32430] ----------------------------------------------- [ErrorId: 1-660bdef5-097bfa366a83b09e2ea78c31]

If priceitems is varchar, can you try this one, without casting(::json)?
json_extract_array_element_text(priceitems, 0)

What Lex said.  There is no data type "json" on Redshift (there is super but that isn't in play in this example. json_extract_path() and json_extract_array_element_text() both operate on text strings that are properly formatted json strings.  No casting is required for your case.
SELECT 
  json_extract_path(
    json_extract_array_element_text(priceitems, 0),
    'amount'
  ) 
FROM 
    expenses

If you want to unnest the whole array into data rows on Redshift you will need to convert the json text to a super type with json_parse().  Unnesting example is at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html#unnest
